# iPython documentation output is incorrectly formatted

Tags: python, ipython

This is a strange issue with ipython that I'm experiencing in my new machine. Whenever I try to print documentation, it comes as such:
[image]

Rather than a neatly formatted output. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Note that usually with `IPython` you'd do `plt.scatter?` for the docs and `plt.scatter??` for the code.

Comment: IPython, like the standard Python interpreter, just prints the `repr` of any expression you type in. And this is what the `repr` of a string looks like—quotes around it, special characters escaped, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try `print`ing it

```
print plt.scatter.__doc__
```

It's simply returning the underlying string representation, so if you want it to format, `print` should do it.

Comment: Even shorter: `help(plt.scatter)`. Funny thing, I don't remember ever having to use print/help to print documentation the right way. Also, DSM just pointer out `plt.scatter?`, which is probably the quickest way.